# Comments count returns 0 but there is 1 comment

Tags: comments, facebook-comments

I use comments box for my page http://osym.gamextreme.ru/work/fb.html. I've left a comment on this page. But graph api (http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://osym.gamextreme.ru/work/fb.html) and div with class fb_comments_count doesn't show any comments at all.

What I've done incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

You have to refresh the page - but the counter does work.
[image]

Comment: I' ve commented that page using 2 different accounts on Facebook but I can't see right comments count. Besides when I log out I can't see my comments, I see only yours.

Comment: Im sorry my friend - the comments plugin **is** working as expected.

Comment: What do you mean? I've registered users using my real emails. And I've confirmed both.

Comment: Here what I see now using first account: http://osym.gamextreme.ru/files/fb/2.png, and second one: http://osym.gamextreme.ru/files/fb/1.png

Comment: I was referring to facebook [Test Users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/).  They are separated from regular users so we wouldnt have seen their posts. But this is not the case...

Comment: and after you refresh there is no difference in the counter?